# Generics Java super

Tags: java, generics, super

Whats wrong with  listNum.add(num) in code below; (Reference- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html)

it gives compilation error as
The method add(capture#1-of ? super Long) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Number)

```
public class GenericSuper {

   List<? super Long> listNum = new LinkedList < Number >();
   List<? super ExportException> listExp= new LinkedList<RemoteException>();

   public List<? super ExportException> addList()
   {
      Number num = 10;
      listNum.add(num);
      RemoteException rme = new RemoteException();
      listExp.add(rme);
      return rme;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not just declaring `listExp` as `List<RemoteException>`, and `listNum` as a `List<Number>`? I suspect you should revisit what bounded wildcards mean.

Comment: I want to store all super classes of long in listNum and  ExportException in listExp. And hence after reading reference as pasted above in query.I have tried to use the lower bounded wild card. Please suggest correct understanding with links and example.

Comment: But `List<? super Long>` means "a list of some type which is Long or a superclass, but I don't know what" - which means you can't add a `Number` to it. (It might have been created as `ArrayList<Long>`, which shouldn't hold a non-Long.)

Answer (score 1):

`listNum` may be an instance of `List<Long>` and you can't add a `Number` to a list of `Long`, as it would throw class cast exceptions.

Solutions:

1. make `listNum` a `List<? super Number>`
2. make `num` a `Long`

Comment: This example is to understand correct usage of lower bounded wildcard. Reference link is pasted in the query above. I want to store all super classes of say ExportException in a list. Can I do it? Is the example above a correct way of testing that? Am I wrong in my understanding of lower bounded wildcard?

Comment: thanks to Jon Skeet for the hint, I have written this code to clarify usage of Super with Generics. The comments explain it all.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main.java.com.mysystems.generics;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.ExportException;
import java.rmi.server.SocketSecurityException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

//peCS
//Consumer super- you want to add item i.e of super type to the collection.
public class GenericSuper {


    List<? super Long> listNum = new LinkedList < Number >();// listNum is variable that can be assigned list of type super class to Long.
    //And you can put Long and its subclass. And you can only get Object type since it can hold anything from Long to Object.

    List<? super ExportException> listExp= new LinkedList<RemoteException>(); // listExp is variable that can be assigned any list of type super class to ExportException. 
    // And you can  put ExportException and all subclasses of ExportException to the list. And you can only get Object type since it can hold anything from ExportException to Object.

    public List<? super ExportException> addList()
    {
        LinkedList < Number > numList = new LinkedList < Number >();

        Number num = 10.10;
        numList.add(num);
        listNum = numList;
        //listNum.add(num); //Compilation error as only long or its subclass can be added.
        listNum.add(20L);

        for(Object e:listNum){ // Note you can only get Object type and will have to use instance of to do anything meaningful.
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        SocketSecurityException sse = new SocketSecurityException("Hello");
       listExp.add(sse);
       return listExp;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not with generics implementation rather its a basic Java Collection framework mistake wherein you cannot add **Number** type to **Long** type.Generics just resolving it in compile time.Had generics was not at this place you would have got run time exception i.e. ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

I think let me give you a strait forward answer : You cannot do that as it should not be supported  .

If you create 
List l = new ArrayList

Then you can add only elements in the list l which extends long only. As at the time of creation you put List in List .

The original object is List . It is possible for a class to have multilevel super classes.  For example suppose Number extends some class say Serializable then it means List cannot hold a serializable which is its uper class .

Hence to aboid this issue it is not allowed in java.

Check PECS principal of genrics.